# Apple reject iPad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

We have developed an iPad application and submited it to the apple store for review after properly testing at our end. Apple rejected our app giving the following reason:-

> We found that your app failed to launch on iPad running iOS 5.0.1, on
>   both Wi-Fi and cellular networks
>
> We encountered the issue when selecting the application on the Home
>   screen - the app displayed a launch image then quit unexpectedly. This
>   may be because iOS 5 uses a watchdog timer for applications; if an
>   application takes too long to complete its initial startup, the
>   operating system terminates the application.
>
> For information about the watchdog timer, please see Technical Q&A:
>   Application does not crash when launched from debugger but crashes
>   when launched by user..
>
> Another possibility could be a missing entitlement. For more
>   information, please see the Technical Note: Resolving "0x800003A",
>   applications not launching and "missing entitlement".

We are not able to understand why Apple has rejected the app since we are not able to reproduce this issue at our end, and Apple's feedback is not very descriptive.

So what can we do to workaround this problem and resubmit it to apple store?

Comment: You need to try it and put some breakpoints, this could be the only possibility to find out where the app exactly is crashing.

Comment: Have you tested a release version of your app in addition to the debug version?

Comment: can you post your applicationdidfinishlaunching method body..

Answer (score 6):

When Apple tested your app, they tried to launch it, and it never finished launching. If it takes too long to launch (5-10 seconds) it will be terminated by springboard and never finish. That's likely what happened. It's also possible that you had bad entitlements, but you probably would have run into that problem sooner.

Is there any chance you're doing synchronous network access on the main thread when your app is launched? This could easily cause this problem. If so, you should fix your app to *never* do synchronous network access on the main thread.

Comment: thanks Kalvin. in app did finish launching we already create a second thread and perform all our operation on that thread.

Comment: @SandeepDhama - Also note that if you are running your application on your device by executing it through Xcode, Xcode disables the watchdog timer.  This may be why it worked in your testing, but not on Apple's end. Always try running your application manually on the device after having hard-killed it in the multitasking interface.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard- Thanks for your help. Our Entitlements was not valid.We have Downloaded the old xCode make the build  again and resubmit it.Our application is now approved by apple.

Answer (score 2):

you need to remove all the synchronous UI/WEB update calls which blocks `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`
to return YES;

`applicationDidFinishLaunching` must return asap without blocking application thread for lets say - 1 second.

move your blocking code to a method and use `performSelector afterDelay` for that.

Comment: Apps should *never* block the main thread.