# iTunes Connect Vague App Rejection - Pulling My Hair Out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

So, I recently uploaded about 9 apps that were mutations of an original one, just with different content and the same framework...

So, today all 9 of the apps went into review at the exact same time although they were each uploaded a day apart, which I thought was really odd. 5 hours later I get 9 rejection emails and the same rejection as follows:

> 2.2
>        We found that your app failed to launch on iPhone 5 running iOS 6, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
>        We encountered the issue when selecting the application on the Home screen - the app displayed a launch image then quit unexpectedly.
>   This may be because iOS 6 uses a watchdog timer for applications; if
>   an application takes too long to complete its initial startup, the
>   operating system terminates the application. 
>        For information about the watchdog timer, please see Technical Q&A: Application does not crash when launched from debugger but
>   crashes when launched by user..
>        Another possibility could be a missing entitlement. For more information, please see the Technical Note: Resolving "0x800003A",
>   applications not launching and "missing entitlement". For discrete
>   code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer
>   Technical Support. Please be sure to:
>
> - include the complete details of your rejection issues
> - prepare any symbolicated crash logs, screenshots, and steps to reproduce the issues for when the DTS engineer follows up. 
>      For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS
>     Application Crash Reports.
>      If you have difficulty reproducing this issue, please try testing the workflow as described in
>     https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/Testing Workflow
>     with Xcode's Archive feature".

I've uploaded a number of apps before and have never received this sort of issue.. So, I followed their suggestions and it's not the dogwatch timer, as the app runs absolutely flawless when ran from xcode on my iPhone 4s with iOS6, and also runs without any issues when I distribute it as ad-hoc enterprise, and sync the app through a .ipa file onto my iphone...

Although, before testing any of this I went through and revoked my development and distribution certificates, went through my keychain and deleted all instances of any certificates related to apps, and keys. Then refreshed everything. All my code signing / provisioning profiles are valid, I re-added my device to the provisioning portal as well.

Does anyone else have any ideas? I'd like to be positive I fixed the problem before uploading my apps again, waiting a week just to be rejected once again and have to start all over. Any help or leads would be greatly appreciated!

I have also double checked all of my info.plist bundle identifiers and they all match the dist and development profiles associated with each app.

Comment: There's nothing the least bit vague in that rejection. Have you actually performed _all_ the suggested steps? One thing to note is that they specifically said iphone **5** whereas you tested on the 4s.

Comment: I have not tested on an actual iPhone 5 device, as I don't have access to one and I don't believe there is a simulator available for one? How am I supposed to work with or around that?

Comment: I just discovered the hardware -> device in the iphone simulator but I'm assuming that doesn't account for hardware specifications for the iphone 5. I'm lost, I have went through everything they've suggested aside from an actual iPhone 5, but I don't have access to one.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547225/apple-reject-ipad-app

Comment: For reference, remember that your app will always run if launched by Xcode as the watchdog timer will be disabled. Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1592/_index.html

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. Although I have no entitlements, as I don't believe they're necessary for this specific app? This app does not use push notifications, nor is it ad hoc. Or am I missing something? 

As far as the watchdog timer goes, again, the app runs fine on my 4s when manually synced and ran as a regular app would be.

Comment: Another issue here is the fact that I have no way to verify if anything I do will resolve the whatever issue is occuring..

Comment: What is your app doing in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`?

Comment: It's just loading the first view

Comment: self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *rootViewController;
rootViewController = [[[WPViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WPViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    
self.viewController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController] autorelease];

self.viewController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try compiling in armv7 only? (forget the armv7s support). By the way, yeah, it's impossible to test it without any iphone5 hardware, and the simulator actually don't simulate anything. With only armv7 feature it should (i really say "should") behave like in iPhone 3G/4/4s on ios6.

Or did you have some runtime behavior depending on the device? What are you actually set on startup?

Look at this post:
http://wanderingcoder.net/original-armv7s-psa/

Even if it talk about linker error, here is the philosophy: Don't publish something you haven't, can't test. Use armv7s only when you will get rich an have an iPhone 5

Comment: Currently it's set to armv7/armv7s. There's no device specific behavior. I will try just armv7. I did read something about holding up the main and it will cause the app to stall out when reviewed, however I don't believe that's the case here. As my didFinishLaunching is not very intensive and simply loads the view.

Comment: I'm confused as the review stated it crashing before even reaching the initial view, and only iPhone 5?.. I'm so lost.

Comment: Ahh, very interesting.. So just to clarify and make sure I understand correctly, running just plain armv7 uses the same stable functionality as pre iPhone 5 devices?

So, this is essentially what I should have?: http://uploadpie.com/l1YrW

Comment: Mmmm, i can't guaranty it. But what i'm sure is that armv7s introduce new integer division arithmetic change and float point arithmetic instruction, . Maybe your code behave faster in some thread and your algorithm behave differently, maybe an exception is thrown and you don't handle it. A Segmentation fault or a bad access exception? If Apple were smart with you they could send you the iPhone 5 error stack, but it seems to hard for them. What i'm sure is that you should not compile it in armv7s until you tested it.

Comment: Alright, well my fingers are crossed that that is the issue. As all my other apps that have been accepted, I just noticed they use only armv6 / armv7 and not armv7s. Well we'll see.. Worse comes to worse I'll find a buddy with an iPhone 5.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got around to finding a friend with an iPhone 5. The crashing WAS due to armv7s architecture being used. So I stripped out all architectures and used only armv7. Worked like a charm and the app ran as smoothly on my 4s as it did on my friend's iphone 5.